The python module sentence-transformers is not found, even though the package is installed
For my python script (as seen below), I use the package sentence-transformer, which contains SBERT models. Even though this package is clearly listed as installed when executing "pip list" and torch is also installed, everything is updated to the newest version, the module still cannot be found.
The script:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

# Load the SBERT model
model = SentenceTransformer('all-mpnet-base-v2')

# Load the dataset
input_file = 'PJ_whole_conversations_row_per_conversation_v1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(input_file)

# Generate embeddings for the "message" column
messages = df['message'].tolist()
embeddings = model.encode(messages, convert_to_numpy=True)

# Save embeddings to NumPy file
output_file_numpy = 'row_per_conversation_embeddings.npy'
np.save(output_file_numpy, embeddings)

print(f'Embeddings have been generated and saved to {output_file_numpy}')

I tried using different environments. I tried executing the script globally with the newest versions of python and the packages. I am coding on Windows 11 as the OS with Visual Studio Code, through which I also tried conda and venv as environments. I changed up the python and package versions to also try out different combinations, thinking that maybe the versions weren't compatible. Each time I got slightly different errors, but it was always a variation of the sentence-transformer not being able to be accessed or not being able to access it properly.
Most commonly I got the following error in some variety depending on which version of python and packages I used:
Exception has occurred: OSError
[WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\nea\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.
  File "C:\Users\saham\OneDrive\4. Semester\Independent Research Project\Python_scripts\row_per_conversation_word embedding.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\nea\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\torch\lib\fbgemm.dll" or one of its dependencies.

Since torch tended to be the issue, I tried de- and reinstalling torch in the various environments, but it never fixed the error. I'm honestly a bit at the end of my rope here and hope that someone might know a good fix.
Like I said, it keeps happening even when it's all installed in a brand new environment and across different version variations.

This may help - https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/failed-to-import-pytorch-fbgemm-dll-or-one-of-its-dependencies-is-missing/201969

Hello, is it useful if I try to install a specific version of torch? Like this pip install torch==2.3.1+cpu torchvision==0.18.1+cpu torchaudio===2.3.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html.

Which Python version do you use?
I am debugging the same issue for a friend, so far my research has discovered that one of sentence_transformers dependencies (sentencepiece) may not compatible with Python 3.12. See this other SO post.
Other cases points to misinstallation (or non-installation) of Pytorch, and suggest to install it manually (beware the Pytorch versions in the links, those are fairly old). References: GitHub 1 , GitHub 2
Please let me know what may work for you, I will update the answer in case my friend manages to solve the issue (hopefully).

The error message above contains Python.3.11 though, plus it's being thrown by torch trying to load torch\lib\fbgemm.dll

3.11.9. I tried a couple of different versions, but same result so far. Thanks for the help! I'll update in case I stumble upon the answer, good luck to you too

Downgrade the python version to 3.9 and everything will be install and work fine
